# How do I save a result of javascript to a file in gulp

Tags: javascript, json, gulp

To lower client machine overhead, I want to save a JSON result of javascript to a file as a build step using gulp. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably work like this (it's untested):

```
var js = require('./js-file.js'),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync('./output.json', js.returnMethod());
```

You could append it to an existing task or add a separate, dedicated one.